# Invalid Procedure Call Or Argument - attempting to dynamically change pivot cache

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to dynamically refresh some pivot tables in Excel. The pivot tables (and connected slicers - each slicer connects to multiple pivots) already exist, the underlying source data table does not. The process is as follows:

- Create new sheet to hold the 'raw' data
- Populate sheet, wrap data into a ListObject (table)
- Create a new pivot cache from the new data
- Unlink the slicers from the pivot tables
- Change the pivot tables' cache to the new cache
- Refresh the pivot tables
- Link the slicers back up
- Delete the data sheet

> ***To clarify the structure:***
>   One data source table. Multiple pivot tables pointing to the source. Multiple slicers, each connected to all the pivot tables (eg Week Ending slicer chages Week Ending on all the pivots)

I'm running into a problem however with step 4. The following code works:

```
'dataTable is a ListObject that was created on a sheet earlier in the function. Can confirm 100% that it exists and is populated.    
Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each pt in PivotSheet.PivotTables
    pt.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=dataTable)
Next pt
```

However, it means one pivot cache per pivot table, which means I run into problems when trying to set up slicers that manipulate multiple pivots - it assumes that each pivot table has a different data source, and so will only let me link the slicer to a single pivot.

I decided the way to go would be to create a single pivot cache, and then link each pivot table to it. This code however does not work, throwing `error 5` at me the first time it is reached:

```
'dataTable is a ListObject that was created on a sheet earlier in the function. Can confirm 100% that it exists and is populated.
Dim pc As PivotCache
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=dataTable)

Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each pt in PivotSheet.PivotTables
    pt.ChangePivotCache pc  'Invalid Procedure Call Or Argument 
Next pt
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two approaches:

```
Dim bCreated              As Boolean
Dim lngMasterIndex        As Long
Dim pt                    As PivotTable

For Each pt In PivotSheet.PivotTables
    If Not bCreated Then

        pt.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                            SourceData:=DataTable)
        bCreated = True
        lngMasterIndex = pt.CacheIndex
    Else
        pt.CacheIndex = lngMasterIndex
    End If
Next pt
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Really ought to expect by now that anything seemingly straightforward in VBA is going to end up with 10 extra lines of throwaway variable declarations, a state-tracking bool and an If-Else block. Cheers!

Comment: Can you explain why this works but the original code doesn't?

Comment: @AJ If memory serves it seems that Excel discards the pivotcache if it isn't connected to a pivot table straight away.

Comment: Thanks, @Rory . That makes sense (I think).

Answer (score 0):

If you hate snorkeling the code, to make it work, this is the short and dirty way to do it:

```
For Each pt in PivotSheet.PivotTables
  On Error Resume Next
    pt.ChangePivotCache pc 'works for the first entry
    pt.CacheIndex = pc.Index 'works for all the others
  On Error GoTo 0
Next PT
```